# 12.04 unable to connect to WEP

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am currently running a dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have been unable to connect stably to my WEP secured WiFi, although I am able to connect to other WPA(2) connections just fine. In the rare occasion that connection is made, there is no internet access. I do not have access to the router settings as it belongs to the landlord.

I have tried:

1. Updating to compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-su
2. Blocking IPv6

But still does not work. `rfkill` shows everything is unblocked.

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTX 460M] [10de:0dd1] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0be9] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Fresco Logic FL1000G USB 3.0 Host Controller [1b73:1000] (rev 04)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5205 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0461:4d99 Primax Electronics, Ltd
```

Could I have some advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you know the WEP passphrase for connecting to your wireless.
Then follow:
1.Can you please delete your WEP connection from the nm-connection-editor?

```
Click on wireless  
Select your wifi connection name  
Click on Delete.
```

2.Once deleted just try searching for your wireless from the networks listed.
3.Connect to that, which will ask you to enter passphrase.

Hope that will solve the issue.

Comment: I've tried that before but the problem remains.